# OData with EF Database First (EF designer from DB)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, odata, asp.net-web-api, ef-database-first

We are currently implementing an OData Service as an alternative to using our own rigid WebApi endpoint.  This sounds great on paper but we have been running into some major issues - most of them having to do with maintainability between updates of the OData endpoint.

We are using the EF Database First method to model our data.  This has issues because once you get the data modeled it doesn't annotate primary keys.  I would expect it to place [Key] attributes on properties but we are having to do this manually:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
...
[Key]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

This seems like something the edmx template file could do automatically but apparently its not built in.

To make matters even more complicated, Updating the model is a pain.  We can't actually just right click on the designer diagram and use the Update Model functionality because its not reliable.  We tried to include a stored procedure into a Model we have already created and it didn't update.  So we have to redo the whole diagram every time we want to make a change.  Plus the code generated for the modeled stored procedure didn't have the return value we desired.  Meaning not only do we have to re-create the diagram every time we make a change and add the keys - but we have to update the stored procedure returns.  That's just a nightmare!

So the real questions are - is there a better practice?  Is using Code First the better solution?  If so, what is the general flow for using Code First and exposing entities via OData?

We are really trying to find a solution that makes OData worth the effort and haven't been able to achieve any success without tons of headaches.  Any perspective on similar projects would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using OData V3 or V4?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/OData/RESTier ?

Comment: I'm using V4.  I also haven't heard of RESTier - I'll take a look.

Comment: After taking a look - im not sure if RESTier is the right option, since its not quite stable yet and really just provides a way to fallback to WebAPI.  It however, has led me to believe that EF Code First might be better.